# Directory Map a Symbolic Link

Tags: php, codeigniter

In a CMS application, I have to access files from another domain both on the same server. From a CI app in "/var/www/vhosts/CMS/httpdocs/", I tried to **directory_map**('/var/www/vhosts/other_domain/httpdocs/assets/') with no success -- white page and no errors.

So I decided to put a symbolic link to the assets directory in the root of the CI application, and used directory_map('./assets/') and directory_map('assets/') and both return a white page and no errors.

Can directory_map or **get_dir_file_info** from the File Helper not follow symbolic links ( follow symLinks is turned on in the .htaccess file )?

If not, how would you suggest that I set up the app so that the assets folder can be acted upon as if it was local to the CI app. As a CMS, I need to upload, copy, move and delete assets and being local would prevent the open_basedir limitations.

This CMS is responsible for 78 sites so having all of the assets together in a sort of homemade cdn is crucial.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: make sure the unix user that CI is running on / owns the files has permissions to access your sym link in the ci application root folder so if you've created your ln in /home/ciap/assetsfromvar/ chmod that so  that your ciap user can access it.  Also depending on how apache is configured you may have to allow the apache user access to that folder too.

Comment: the symbolic link is 777 root|root and all of the asset folders and files are 777 root|root. Do I need to go further than that?

Comment: also, the obvious question -- is directory_map unable to extend beyond its parent domain even if I give it the FULL path from / of the server?

Comment: Don't know about directory_map never used CI myself always found it kinda horrible so avoided it.  Locally I have my web files in /var/www/html/ and I have a storage file for my cdn in /home/cdn/san/ I have a ln -s in /var/www/html/cdn/ -> /home/cdn/san/ I then have 777 set on the sym link in the var folder and file ownership of all files is by the cdn user as all the files live in the cdn user space.  My apache runs as httpd but can access it all just fine.  Hope that makes sense

Comment: @Dave, could you turn your comment(s) into an answer so that I can mark it as resolved since it fixed my issue and THANKS!

Comment: comments now posted as an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure the unix user that CI is running on / owns the files has permissions to access your sym link in the ci application root folder so if you've created your ln in /home/ciap/assetsfromvar/ chmod that so that your ciap user can access it. Also depending on how apache is configured you may have to allow the apache user access to that folder too

Don't know about directory_map never used CI myself always found it kinda horrible so avoided it. Locally I have my web files in /var/www/html/ and I have a storage file for my cdn in /home/cdn/san/ I have a ln -s in /var/www/html/cdn/ -> /home/cdn/san/ I then have 777 set on the sym link in the var folder and file ownership of all files is by the cdn user as all the files live in the cdn user space. My apache runs as httpd but can access it all just fine. Hope that makes sense